# Why the button stays always hidden?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

```
<div class="app__land-bottom" v-if="isVisible">
  <a href="#projects">
    <img ref="arrowRef" id="arrow" src="./../assets/down.png" alt srcset />
  </a>
</div>
```

In Vue3 setup isn't working, but on Vue2 is working the following solution for not displaying a button based on scrolling.

```
VUE3
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from "vue";

let isVisible = ref(false);

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    hideArrow();
  });
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", () => {
    hideArrow();
  });
});

const hideArrow = () => {
  const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
  if (currentScroll > 100) {
    isVisible = false;
  } 
  else if (currentScroll < 100) {
    isVisible = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

```
VUE2
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.hideArrow)
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: false, 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hideArrow() {
      const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
      if (currentScroll > 100) {
        this.isVisible = false;
      } else if (currentScroll < 100) {
        this.isVisible = true;
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

In vue2 the solution is working but on Vue3, not. Any suggestions?
I don't understand exactly where the problem is? It would be helpful an answer.

Comment: You're misusing a ref. You should never reassign a variable.

Comment: can you give more context?

Comment: Check how refs are used, https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref . If isVisible variable is just reassigned, it has no chances to be reactive.

Answer (score 3):

when mutating your ref: `isVisible` you need to type: `isVisible.value` instead of `isVisible`

your `hideArrow` function should be:

```js
const hideArrow = () => {
  const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
  if (currentScroll > 100) {
    isVisible.value = false;
  } 
  else if (currentScroll < 100) {
    isVisible.value = true;
  }
}
```

for more details: check [Ref docs in Vue](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)